# select id from the select gender dropdown list

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

I have a dropdown list of gender. I am getting the values from my table 'candidate' and in this table i have a field which is actually a foreign key to another table.

The field is gender_code_cde, and the table name is gender_code. Now gender_code contains 2 rows. and id and a description. Its structure is like:

1->Male
2->Female

Its being displayed in dropdown list. but I want to get the id 1 if male is selected and id 2 if female is selected. My code is below:

```
<p>
<label for ="gender">Gender:</label>
<?php
   $query = mysql_query("select * from gender_code"); // Run your query
   echo '<select name="GENDER">'; // Open your drop down box
   //Loop through the query results, outputing the options one by one
   while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) 
  {
     echo '<option value="'.$row['gender_cde'].'">'.$row['gender_dsc'].'</option>';
  }
  echo '</select>';
?>
</p>
```

I am working in codeIgniter.

Comment: you want to rewrite this to CI?

Comment: well when you want to get the id, when it is selected or some button click ? you can do both by jquery

Comment: I don't want to rewrite it. Its already written in CI. All i want is the gender_cde which is gender_code_cde in my table.

Comment: so when you selected male then post the value to a controller and the insert/update the value to your table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

// this will alert value of dropdown whenever it will change

```
<script>
function getvalue(val)
{
   alert(val);
}
</script>
    <p>
    <label for ="gender">Gender:</label>
    <?php
       $query = mysql_query("select * from gender_code"); // Run your query
       echo '<select name="GENDER" id="Gender" onchange="getvalue(this.value)">'; // Open your drop down box
       //Loop through the query results, outputing the options one by one
       while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) 
      {
         echo '<option value="'.$row['gender_cde'].'">'.$row['gender_dsc'].'</option>';
      }
      echo '</select>';
    ?>
    </p>
```

Comment: function create() {
  $data = array(
  'gender_code_cde' => $this->input->post('gender')
// more code here. more data inputs
);
}
In my create method i am doing some thing like this.

Comment: Its working. But the problem is that if I have selected male then '1' should be stored in my table.

Comment: you can create form and post it it is simple. not to worry abt it just  wrap select box with form give some action and at other page u can get value of gender by $_REQUEST['GENDER'] now u can perform any database with it . if u dont want to create form use ajax

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript, you can get the value with native JS.

```
var e = document.getElementById("give-the-select-element-an-id");
var gender_cde = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
```

If, you want it back at the server, it will come in to PHP as `$_GET['GENDER']` or `$_POST['GENDER']` depending on if the form does a POST or a GET request.

Answer (score 0):

If you are submitting a (POST) form and this is inside that form you can access the the value (id) from CodeIgniter's `$_POST` wrapper: `$this->input->post('GENDER');`. I don't use CodeIgniter so I could be wrong, but it will be located in your `$_POST` array from PHP.

If you just want to replicate the variable somewhere on the page you can just `echo` it. Or set via js/jQuery with `document.getElementById('#something').value = value;` or `jQuery('#something').html(value);`.

You should also change the following:

- use a `foreach` in place of your while:

  ```
  foreach ($query as $row) {
      echo $row['gender_x'] . $row['gender_y'];
  }
  ```
- use the CodeIgniter SQL wrapper instead of depreciated PHP functions. The query part is `$this->db->query('SELECT statement goes here');`. You should look at your CodeIgniters' version documentation for a more in depth explanation.

**EDIT:** To make it a bit more clear, an example:

```
$query = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM gender_code');
foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
    echo '<option value="' . $row->gender_cde . '">' . $row->geneder_dsc . '</option>';
}
```

This is assuming you have setup the previous calls in CodeIgniter. Please see http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/examples.html and you may wish to read http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/

Comment: I have tried foreach loop but its not displaying. Let me send you the code that i attempted. It wasn't working so i had to stick with the query_fetch blah blah which i hate :(

Comment: $this->db->query('select * from gender_code');
echo '<select name="GENDER">';
foreach ($query as $row) {
echo $row['gender_cde'] . $row['gender_dsc'];
}

Comment: I edited my answer to give a better example. I was putting the base down before, but they needed filling in.

Comment: Since CodeIgniter is MVC this should be split anyway. The db call should be in the Model, which is called by the Controller and then sent to the View as an Object/Array/Value. So the `foreach()` is all that should be in the View.

Comment: It should work that way but once i am out of the view how am i going to get this value? Secondly when i try to insert it into the table it gives me a database error since the gender_code_cde is actually a foreign key of gender_code table.

Comment: The controller should already have the value which was sent to the view as it [the controller] initiated the call to the model and then rendered the view and gave the view the value.

Could you show us your insert query? As being a foreign key isn't an issue unless you're trying to do something out of the ordinary.